# Return error message if the command is wrong in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on this project where I set up some commands that my TelegramBot can execute. And I would like to add an error message if the command written is wrong. Here is the code:

```
void handleNewMessages(int numNewMessages){

 Serial.print("Handle New Messages: ");

    Serial.println(numNewMessages);

     for (int i = 0; i < numNewMessages; i++){

// Chat id of the requester

String chat_id = String(bot.messages[i].chat_id);

if (chat_id != chatId){
  bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Unauthorized user", "");
  continue;
}

// Print the received message
String text = bot.messages[i].text;
Serial.println(text);

String fromName = bot.messages[i].from_name;

if (text == "/FlashOn") {
  flashState = HIGH;
  digitalWrite(LED, flashState);
}

if (text == "/FlashOff") {
  flashState = LOW;
  digitalWrite(LED, flashState);
}

if (text == "/photo") {
  sendPhoto = true;
  Serial.println("New photo request");
}

if (text == "/PIRON"){
  PirControler = 1;
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "PIR Sensor is ON, you will get a notification if a motion is detected.", "");
}

if (text == "/PIROFF"){
  PirControler = 0;
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "PIR sensor is OFF, you will no longer receive any notification.", "");

if (text == "/start"){
  String welcome = "Hi sir, here are the commands I can execute for you :\n";
  welcome += "/Photo : Take a new photo.\n";
  welcome += "/FlashOn : Turns LED On.\n";
  welcome += "/FlashOff : Turns LED off\n";
  welcome += "/PIRON : Activate your PIR sensor.\n";
  welcome += "/PIROFF : Shut your PIR sensor down.\n";
  // welcome += "/readings : request sensor readings\n\n";
  welcome += "You'll receive a photo whenever motion is detected.\n";
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, welcome, "Markdown");
}
/*else {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "I don't understand, sorry. Refer to the commands I showed you above.", "");      
} **(Here is the message that I'd like to add)**
}
}
```

However, by trying to add the last line,

```
/*else {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, "I don't understand, sorry. Refer to the commands I showed you above.", "");      
}*/
```

It returns an error to all the right commands except for the "/start" one.

Any ideas on how I could do that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like you want `else if`s rather than a separate `if` for each test.

Comment: Okay, how could I put this in practice, @user4581301 ?

Comment: Use switch/case statement.  Return the error in the default case.

Comment: @stark in C and C++ `switch` is notoriously hard to get working with strings because it requires integers in the `case`s. I'll often use a `std::map<std::string, void (*)()>` to map a string to a function and then I could `mymap.at(text)();` to run the function or throw exception if `text`'s not in the map. The exception handler would send the error message. Since the code here looks very Arduino,  `std::map` and `std::string` probably aren't available.

Comment: I think I'll keep @user4581301 way to do that, stark, thanks for your answer though. What you guys are talking about is just scary for me ^^ And yes btw, it's an arduino code !

Comment: Groovy. Let me add the arduino tag. Some arduinio guru may have a better solution  than my general C++approach.

Comment: It's not hard to find the string in a table, then switch on the index.  You end up with cleaner code then all those if-else statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the example smaller

```cpp
if (text == "/FlashOn") {
  do stuff
}

if (text == "/start"){
  do stuff
}
else {
  report error
}
```

This code will always test `if (text == "/start")` regardless of the outcome of `if (text == "/FlashOn")` and if `text` is "/FlashOn", it cannot be "/start" and will execute the `else` and print the error message.

Solution

```cpp
if (text == "/FlashOn") {
  do stuff
}

else if (text == "/start"){
  do stuff
}
else {
  report error
}
```

Now `if (text == "/start")` will not be tested and the `else` case will not be run if `text == "/FlashOn"`.

What this looks like if fully indented and bracketed:

```cpp
if (text == "/FlashOn") {
  do stuff
}
else {
  if (text == "/start"){
    do stuff
  }
  else {
    report error
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user4581301 ! I just tested this out and it worked perfectly :) Problem solved.

Comment: I did it this way, I guess it's okay since it's working : `if (text == "/FlashOn") { sutff }--> else if (text == "/start"){ stuff } --> else {stuff);`